# Why did Xavier not contact the US and Russian military telepathically?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-first-class

I saw *X-Men: First Class* a long time ago. I have been getting a doubt about the climax.

We are all very familiar with the power and abilities of *Professor Charles Francis Xavier*. Let's check what [wiki (under powers and abilities column, bottom of the page)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_X) is telling about him:

> Professor X is a mutant who possesses vast telepathic powers, and is among the strongest and most powerful telepaths in the Marvel Universe. **He is able to perceive the thoughts of others or project his own thoughts within a radius of approximately 250 miles (400 km).**

and at the start of the same page

> Xavier is paraplegic, although his body houses **one of the world's most powerful mutant minds.**

Now remember the climax scene of this movie:

> Magneto:
>   Take off your blinders,
>   brothers and sisters.The real enemy is out there. I feel their guns moving in the water. Their metal targeting us. Americans, Soviets, humans.....Go ahead, Charles. Tell me I'm wrong.

On that time Charles can use his powers and he can say to all Soviets/humans/Americans, "this area is secure. All are under control. Don't launch missiles.". **Why is he silent?** If he had done like this maybe he wouldn't have been injured.

Why is Charles silent even he has a powerful mind?

Comment: Why would that help?  If anything it might make them more likely to fire out of fear.  The humans are scared, a voice telling them its all ok is unlikely to change that - they will follow orders and eliminate the strange threat.

Comment: "You always fear what you don't understand"

Comment: @iandotkelly:: Yes I agree. But he can tell to only the commander/main person that this area is secure now. Because convincing one person is very easy I think. So he don't pass any commands to fire

Comment: Whilst I believe Napoleon is right (+1), I'd point out 2 more things: 1) your link is from the Comic book version of Xavier, not the Movie. Whilst the movies are derived directly from the books, they operate in a different continuity/universe so the two iterations psychic strength may vary and 2) Xavier is still young in first class, his powers are not yet fully developed/explored. Remember, he is boosted significantly by Cerebro when contacting mutants at range, even in X1. He may simply be out of range of the Subs/Ships.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forget why they were targetting them in the first place. The military of both the Soviets and the US didn't care if it was all *Shaw*'s plan and if that threat was eliminated already. All they saw was a group of people with tremendous power and which they didn't understand. They feared them and thought them to be a danger for human society. And that is exactly the reason why they aimed their missiles at them.

So *Magneto*, even if thinking a bit one-sided and blinded by hatred and fear, wasn't so wrong in his assessment that *"the real enemy is out there"* and *Charles* could certainly *not* tell him that he was wrong.

In this situation, one of those mutants telepathing his voice into the heads of all those fearful and narrow-minded generals and saying *"everything's fine"* wouldn't have helped the slightest bit to make those mutants seem less like a threat for them, rather on the contrary.

Comment: it's also pretty known that xavier could end all conflicts and yet does nothing... he can't "just" project his thought, he can make you think what he wants you to think, there's a story about a very powerful mutant (can't remember the name) who is too powerful to be left alone, so xavier literally makes him unaware of his own powers in the hope he won't use them.